# How to save the minimum path sum in a recursive function?

Tags: python, algorithm

This is my solution to *given a matrix m x n, find the minimum path sum*. It works fine however, I'm not sure how to modify it to see the path / save it in some list, how can this be done?

```
def get_path(matrix, x, y, seen):
    if (x, y) in seen:
        return seen[x, y]
    x_end = len(matrix) - 1
    y_end = len(matrix[0]) - 1
    current = matrix[x][y]
    if x == x_end and y == y_end:
        return current
    possible_moves = []
    if x < len(matrix) - 1:
        possible_moves.append([x + 1, y])
    if y < len(matrix[0]) - 1:
        possible_moves.append([x, y + 1])
    results = [
        current + get_path(matrix, *possible, seen) for possible in possible_moves
    ]
    current_best = min(results)
    seen[x, y] = current_best
    return current_best
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to.

After `get_path` returns, start from 0,0 look for a move where `seen[x', y'] = seen[x,y] - matrix[x,y]`.
If you have equality (both moves work) pick whatever you want (equals paths).
Keep going until you reach the end.